# From where to import type Reference for Firebase storage items in - React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, types, firebase-storage

I want to fetch items from Firebase storage and set them into the state. From where I can import type "Reference" which my IDE is recommending me to use?

```
const ListOfFiles: React.FC = () => {
  // Using "react-redux-firebase"
  const firebase = useFirebase()

  // My question is concerning about what type to put here and where to take it from
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState<Reference[]>([])

  const getFiles = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const filesPath = `path/to/my/files`
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(filesPath)
    const result = await storageRef.listAll()

    setItems(result.items)
  }, [firebase, itemId, workspaceId])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getFiles()
  }, [getFiles, itemId, workspaceId])

  return items.map((item) => <span>{item.name}</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put there the type of your `items`

```js
type Item = {
  name: string
  .. other fields ...
}

... 

const [items, setItems] = React.useState<Item[]>([])

... 

setItems(result.items as Item[]) // You need to cast your content to Items, because typescript doesn't know what result.items is
```

---

If you are wondering why your IDE was recommending you `Reference`, it is because typescript tried to automatically understand the type of your state hooks. It noticed that you use `setItems` here:

```js
setItems(result.items)
```

and it knows that result.items is of `Reference[]` type, where Reference is a generic type returned by Firebase (that doesn't know the form of your data, so can't return a more specific type). So typescript (and your IDE) suggests you:

> Hey, you are missing the type of `items` and `setItems`. Considering that further down your code you assign them a `Reference[]` object, you probably want that as your type.

The fact is, you know the **actual** properties of your items, so you can provide a more detailed info by providing a specific type